# Система чата на PHP, с возможностью отправки и заполнения произвольных форм

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, chat

прошу вас помочь, у меня есть система чата, написанная на PHP+AJAX, в ней есть возможность отправки произвольных форм, к примеру для заполнения данных, но ajax чат работает так, что он обновляется каждые 2 секунды, и как только ты начинаешь вводить в поле какие-то данные, то чат обновляется, и выходит что пользователь не может ввести никаких данных, как это можно было бы исправить?

Comment: Обновляется каждые 2 секунды? )) за такой чат "разработчику" руки сломать надо )) Если серьёзно, необходимо быстро удалить данный код и написать нормальный чат с использованием `WebSocket` как пример

Comment: смотрите сама сложность в том, что сама форма в самом чате, то есть в области обновления данных.. и просто не дает возможности пользователю, заполнить эту форму, и дальше продолжить чатиться..

Comment: Если честно, я даже не хочу представлять, что там сделано, уже страшно, такой чат переделывать не получиться,  нужно менять её, но дело ваше ))

Comment: Не должно быть ни какой "области обновления данных". Не должно стираться все и заново отрисовываться. Уже отрисованное должно аккуратно модифицироваться, возможно вообще только дописыванием в конец. Особенно странно выглядят совместно ajax, который вообще то предназначен для получения и последующей модификации небольших областей сайта, вкупе с перерисовкой целого окна чата целиком

Comment: По брацки =)
Если нужен чат, лучше поднять сервер на Rocket или MatterMost. Там и ботов прикрутить можно. 
Самописные чаты - боль.